# formatting same date in different format using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Hi I want to  format date (05/07/2018 17:04:00) to (20180507) inside jmeter. Please help me.using some sampler. I need to use the date variable to make another JSON call.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) with the below code in the code area:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;

SimpleDateFormat source = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date date = source.parse(vars.get("C_ticketcreatedate"));
String newDate = target.format(date);
vars.put("NewDate", newDate);
```

Now you can use the new date format like this `${NewDate}`

[image]

Comment: If i get the input date in a variable. how should i use it? 
Actually i am getting the date as JSON response . I am fetching the date into a variable value by regular expression extractor.
Now I want the date variable to format into the specified format.

Comment: Replace the variable DATE in the beanshell code with your regular expression variable, and then in your JSON call use ${NewDate} instead of the date value.

Comment: I am taking input from csv. then making two calls .1st call is to extract date And within that loop itself i need to make another request using the date. I have Used regular expression extractor to get the date now before i make the second call, i need to format the Url(http://pdimrestdev.fpl.com/tcms/tcmsticket/20180507/3?format=Json)and then call the service and do some validation.                    So the logic is 1st hit the Smart service using  premise ID.
Then retrieve  date information from there.
Parse them altogether to make a TCMS service call.

Comment: Put the above beanshell between the two calls, and replace the second call with this ((pdimrestdev.fpl.com/tcms/tcmsticket/${NewDate}/3?format=Json)

Comment: Yeah I tried that, option but the problem is when i am already inside a http sampler I cannot add any more sampler. i get the beanshell assertion option.

Comment: I am able to make the 1st call. the problem also able to extract the value. But the problem is with formatting the url with date inside that loop for that instance and make another call.

Comment: I am able to make the 1st call.also able to extract the value. But the problem is with formatting the url with date inside that loop for that instance and make another call.

Comment: I edited the answer with a snapshot of the structure that you should have

Comment: from My 1st JSON response the extractor variable that i use is named as C_TicketNumber and the other is C_TicketCreateDate. before making the next call i make the code change in BeanShell Sampler in below format import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
ticketcreatedate = vars.get("C_TicketCreateDate");
SimpleDateFormat source = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date ticketcreatedate = source.parse(vars.get("DATE"));
String newDate = target.format(DATE);
vars.put("NewDate", newDate); BUT NO DATA

Comment: I added the below code the variable that is likewise: regular expression:ticketCreateDate":"(.*?)"    Name of created variable:C_TicketCreateDate.  templete $1$. but still the date is not getting populated.   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
//ticketcreatedate = vars.get("C_TicketCreateDate");
SimpleDateFormat source = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date date = source.parse(vars.get("ticketCreateDate"));
String newDate = target.format(date);
vars.put("NewDate", newDate);

Comment: ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: evalSourced file: inline evaluation of: import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.text.DateFormat;  ticketcreatedat . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation source.parse 
WARN o.a.j.p.j.s.BeanShellSampler: Exception executing script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.text.DateFormat;  ticketcreatedat . . . '': Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation source.parse

Comment: Are you using the same beanshell from the above answer?

Comment: So I was able to fetch the Ticket Number from the 1st reququest In the below url "3" is the ticket number. but but not able to fetch ticket date after formatting in beanshell sampler. http://pdimrestdev.fpl.com/tcms/tcmsticket/${NewDate}/3?format=Json

Comment: Yes i am using the beanshell sampler.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language like:

```
vars.put('date', Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', '05/07/2018 17:04:00').format('yyyyMMdd'))
```

After that you can access converted date as `${date}` or [`${__V(date)}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) where required

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jmeter `__time()` function to format the date and time .

in your case use `${__time(yyyymmdd,)}` to generate the date

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY9YM.png)

For More information

[Jmeter __time Function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)

You can follow [this Blogs](https://www.redline13.com/blog/category/jmeter/) for information on JMeter

Answer (score 0):

The above code is not working. From the response I am getting as 17-Apr-2020 needs to change as 17/04/2020 and send to the corresponding request.

[image: import java.text.SimpleDateFormat]

```
import java.text.DateFormat;

SimpleDateFormat source = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY");
SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
Date date = source.parse(vars.get("C_Date"));
log.info("Date value="+date);
String newDate = target.format(date);
log.info("newDate value="+newDate);
vars.put("NewDate", newDate);][1]][1]
```